# Where is the source of the media items filter

Tags: media-library

I couldn't find the source in the php files. What is generating the select drop-down for the attachment filters in the media library?

[image: media items filter]

Comment: The actual select looks like it's made by backbone in wp-includes\js\media-views.js, about line 5752 onwards, but I don't really speak backbone.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Go to `wp-includes` and then open file `media.php` in line number 1907 you will find: »All media items«.

Comment: 1. This doesn't solve the issue. 2. NEVER edit core files.

Comment: The question was only where is the source file for All Media Items

Comment: That explains where the strings are localized. However, I asked about the drop-down select element.